# How can I fix this kind of bug

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
-(void)GrabbingProcess:(void (^)())block;
{
    AssertNonMainThread;
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (self.OtherGrabbingIndicator == 0)
        {
            self.isStillLoading = true;
        }
        self.OtherGrabbingIndicator ++;
        AssertMainThread
    }];

    block();


    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        [self updateStatusAtList];
        self.OtherGrabbingIndicator --;
        if (self.OtherGrabbingIndicator ==0)
        {
            self.isStillLoading = false;
        }
        AssertMainThread
    }];
}
```

Basically, the code is set up so that self.OtherGrabbingIndicator++ will always be balanced with self.OtherGrabbingIndicator--

I couldn't think of any reason why it would fail. It doesn't use to fail.

Now, once in a while it fails. self.OtherGrabbingIndicator would hover at 2 or 1 and all the threads have stopped. Somehow some ++ are not balanced by the --. But how can that be?

I have no idea how.

I checked around that there is no way self.OtherGrabbingIndicator is changed anywhere else.

One thing I plan to do is to add the value of a block in some array and remove those blocks appropriately. The problem is if I know the block how do I know what code that blocks represent?

It used to work fine and now it doesn't. This drives me nuts.

The only way I can think of is that somehow block() fails to complete but which block fails to complete and how can that happens?

If I press pause, all the threads are empty.

Update: Adding @synchronized() to the ++ and -- solves the problem. However, it DOESN'T make sense.

It should still work without @synchronized because mainQueue has only 1 maximum thread and execute things one at a time.

Comment: No comments just downvotes. What the hell is this? Yes it's difficult problem. I've tried many things. I simply cannot think of any reason why the code can fail. It's a very simple code.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have no final answer for you. However, I did experience something similar recently with NSOperations and I will share it with you.

A few questions about your code:

Does the first block in addOperationWithBlock need to complete before the "block()" call ca be executed ?

Does the second block require both other operation to be completed before being executed ?

In my case, the operations where added in the proper order but based on the thread scheduling of the operation queue (which was lower than some other thread that needed the operation result) they were executed too late and made the code fail.

I do not know how time critical is your grabbing process, but in my case the use of NSOperation in a time critical part of my application was never working 100% of the time. Therefore, I redesigned to use an NSThread of which we could control the priority and since then everything works fine.

My conclusion after this experience is that NSOperation is a great tool because it is simple to use but is not of much help in time critical situation because it is not really meant for that use case.

Hope this helps, best of luck to you.

Comment: No it doesn't. What happen is I do not really care whether the ++ is executed before, after, or at the same time with -- and block(). All that matter is for every ++ there is --. Also because mainQueue only has 1 concurrency, then yes, the ++ will be executed first. It's not important at all.

Comment: Adding  work though. However, that still doesn't make sense. All mainQueue threads should be synchronized even without .